# How the unreactivity of lithium hydride makes it useful in synthesis of other useful hydrides?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have seen the following chemical property of lithium hydride in the textbook which seems to be incomplete:

> Lithium Hydride is rather unreactive at moderate temperatures with ${O_2}$ or
> ${Cl_2}$.It is therefore, used in the synthesis of other useful hydrides.
>
> $\ce{8LiH + Al2Cl6 -> 2LiAlH4 + 6LiCl}$
>
> $\ce{2LiH + B2H6 -> 2LiBH4 }$

But why the unreactivity of lithium hydride makes it useful in synthesis of other useful hydrides?

Comment: "Usefulness" is a subjective term and cannot be judged outside the context. What textbook you've seen it in?

Comment: here is the link for the page(http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?kech2=2-7) (page 15 pdf )(288)

Comment: The equations make no sense. Not only are they unbalanced, but they have different elements in and out.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake,it was just an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lithium hydride is by no means unreactive towards air.  In powdered form it can react with air at low humidity forming the oxide, hydride and carbonate; if the air has higher humidity lithium hydride can combust spontaneously.  Pellets are less violent but still not fully stable in air containing water vapor (as air typically does).  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydride).

Lithium hydride is *less* reactive than heavier alkali metal hydrides.  The textbook may be referring to chemists being better able to minimize reactions with the surroundings using lithium hydride; thus better able to target the intended synthesis reaction.